# Minimum water pressure for swimming pool boiler?

Tags: hvac

I have a swimming pool gas fired boiler (Crown Aruba) 150,000BTU. It is NOT a closed loop system. It takes the water out of the swimming pool, heats it in the boiler, and dumps the heated water back into the pool. Is there a minimum water pressure that I need to have in the boiler?

Comment: what size is your circulating pump for this?

Comment: This does not appear to add up. Crown Arubas appear to be cast-iron boilers, and if you are running pool water *directly through* a cast iron boiler *without* a heat exchanger the corrosion should put an end to that in short order, while turning your pool water orange. I find no mention of a "pool heating variant" of a Crown Aruba, just pipes left, pipes right, and pipes top variants.

Comment: Swimming pool water is so corrosive that titanium heat exchangers are fairly normal to handle it....

Comment: It is actually a solar tank but conceptually was easier to describe as a swimming pool. It is untreated water and has so far lasted 25 years. It has two circulating pumps one on the boiler and one at the tank. I tried, unsuccessfully, to upload pictures of.the pumps.

Comment: If the pics are on your PC, simply [edit] your question and drag/drop them into the text edit box. The site will recognize the drop, upload the image to their host, then give you an "OK" button to hit. If you can't get that, then just put the links into a comment, someone will embed them for you.